# Is it possible to have an option parameter for executing a sqlite statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I query the sqlite db quite a few times and with some queries I pass in the row from a csv file to insert and some queries I just select with one query.

DB Manager class:

```
class DatabaseManager(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, arg, arg2=None):
        self.cursor.execute(arg, arg2)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.cursor

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

So an example:

Query1: `db.query('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO randomtable VALUES (?,?,?,?)', row)`

Query2: `db.query('select * from random_tabletwo')`

Or would I need to create two methods which have the same exact code but different arguments?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman for the method query can I send queries with various arguments or would I need to repeat code for different arguments. I read somewhere it may be possible somehow using * but unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit your `query()` method as follows, I believe it should then work correctly for both of your example uses:

```
def query(self, *args):
    self.cursor.execute(*args)
    self.conn.commit()
    return self.cursor
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I missed the *args when executing, examples were showing me to add the number of arguments there.